# Minimum deployment target for Storekit

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

What's the minimum deployment target that i need to set for Storekit in Xcode? Can it work with deployment target of 5.0?

Comment: Depends on what API's in StoreKit you want to use. Some are available in as early as iOS 3.0 but some iOS 6.0. So check the API's you are using.

Comment: Xcode is giving me the error of "Symbol not found: _OBJC_METACLASS_$_SKStoreProductViewController" if i try to run it on IOS 5 simulator. Does it mean i need to set my deployment target higher or it can still run on older IOS device?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKITunesProductViewController_Ref/SKStoreProductViewController.html look at the docs and see when it is available from, in that case it is iOS 6 and above.

Comment: Will Apple reject the app if i release with a deployment target of 5.0?

Comment: Not for setting your deployment target to iOS 5.0, but if your app crashes then yes.

Comment: If Xcode gives me the error above, does it mean it will crash when it runs on iOS 5 device as well?

Comment: I will let you figure that one out...

Comment: I don't have iOS 5 device. Can let me know?